# DHTMLX export to excel OpenXml version issue

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX to display data in a asp.net website which has functionality to export result to an excel file. To do so I am using DHTMLX.Export.Excel dll which internally uses OpenXml ( DocumentFormat.OpenXml).

But problem is that DHTMLX uses Version=**2.0.5022.0** but on server my various exisiting forms uses  DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=**2.5.5631.0** . So is there any possibilty of having any of these below cases.

1. Have DHTMLX which uses version 2.5 of OpenXML  or
2. Any other way to genarate excel by any other way in DHTMLX.

Comment: 1) you could try using assembly binding redirects 2) that's too broad of a question for SO

Comment: @mason..Thanks for your suggestion..finally I managed by reverting to old version of OpenXML.. fortunatley code did not casused any problem because of previous version of DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed by reverting to old version of OpenXML.. fortunatley code of other functionalities and forms did not casused any problem.It took previous version of DLL without affecting any functionality where OPENXml was used.